# Is it within code to run ent conduit into a junction box on the exterior of the home?

Tags: code-compliance, conduit, telephone, coaxial-cable

I am in the construction process for a new home.  I asked the Low Voltage Contractor to run conduit to about 13 places inside the house.  In addition to that I asked for a run to the exterior of the house to connect to the telecom box outside, so that future runs for cable, satellite, fiber, etc, would be a simple task of just pulling through the conduit already connected to the house from inside the box, even once we finish the basement.

After making this request I learned that:

> ENT shall not be used in the following:
>
> (8) Where exposed to the direct rays of the sun, unless identified as
>   sunlight resistant

I also did not know at the time that the Low Voltage Contractor is not the one who will install the telecom box.  Right now the conduit on the  outside of the home looks like this:

[image: Conduit on the Exterior of the Home]

Because the house next door is already almost finished, I learned today that the telecom box will look exactly like this:

[image: Telecom Box]

**Will the cable company attach the conduit to the telecom box from inside the back so that it is inside the box?**

**Even if so, will this then be code compliant since the conduit is technically not directly in the sunlight anymore?  would there possibly be rain and water damage in the home from this?**

**If not, what needs to be done?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hole should be sealed at the exit point prior to the box being installed and it would be code compliant.